# Extending Splendid CRM Modules

Tags: c#, .net, open-source, crm

I have gone through some open source CRM and found Splendid CRM with source code.
The Splendid CRM covers all my requirement but still I have to add two more modules in that.. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create new modules in SplendidCRM.  SplendidCRM is data-driven, so there is a fair amount of work creating all the data necessary to render a module.  The Professional and Enterprise editions have a Module Builder that can help create the data, but you can certainly do it manually.  There is a Module Development Guide at http://www.splendidcrm.com/Documentation/tabid/233/rvdwktid/community-edition-module-development-guide-138/Default.aspx

The best advice is to copy the code and the data for a smilar module and just rename the old to the new.

Comment: Is there a guide for Module builder for professional/enterprise editions as well?